# this.props.matches are not received when a route is loaded from <Match> in PreactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, preact, preact-router

Following is my code. All the necessary imports like `Match` are present in the file.

**app.js**

```
<Match path="/">
 if (path === '/registerParent') {
   return (<div><RegisterParent path="/registerParent"/></div>);
 }
</Match>
<Router>
 <Route1 path="/route1"/>
 <Route2 path="/route2"/>
</Router>
```

When I am routing the user to `/registerParent` using a button click, my route() function looks like this below :

```
routeUserToRegisterParent() {
  route('/registerParent?id=12345');
}
```

12345 is attached to the route as a query parameter.

**The problem is, when I execute above code, it throws following error as it cannot find this.props.matches in the props object :**

```
Cannot read property id of undefined.
```

But when I load my route from `<Router>` instead of `<Match>`, it works properly and this.props.matches is also received.